Time series decomposition on discontinuous data
I have a activity interevent time data like this:

timestamp           activity interevent time
2017-10-25 18:58:51   1.733103e+05 mins
2017-11-16 17:36:42   3.159785e+04 mins
2017-11-16 17:37:05   3.833333e-01 mins
2017-12-14 11:55:29   3.997840e+04 mins
2017-12-14 11:56:15   7.666667e-01 mins
...


(the first timestamp is not shown here because there is no interevent time for that row as it is the start of the calculation)
As you can see, the hours, days, months are not continuous:
2017-10-25 18h is not followed by 2017-10-25 19h;
2017-10-25 is not followed by 2017-10-26
...
Moreover, because the value is about interevent time, you can not say that at the hour of 2017-10-25 19h has interevent time 0min. You can only consider it as missing.
My questions are:

when you have such data, can you still do time series decomposition with methods like Moving average, or the mstl() function in R package "forecast"?
if not, what other method you can do to check the seasonality and de-season this?

